# Toolbar background missing and moved Title after adding ListView (Android)

Tags: android, toolbar

I've recently tried to add a list view to display local Bluetooth devices.

(Please see images)

Rendered Image looks fine

[image]

Consequently, the background of the toolbar isn't visible (presumed behind the list view) and the Title has moved down the page. I also have two buttons labelled 'Scan' and 'Refresh' in the toolbar, these are operational with the current list view position, however if I position it on top of the table, they are visible but do not work.

I am extending AppCompatActivity

Screenshot of app on phone

[image]

I believe the problem is in the main layout as the problem has only come about since implementing the list view.

I'm new to Android and this is one of my first post so if I've missed anything important e.g. any additional code please let me know!!

Thank you in advance.

Main Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
/>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Local Environmental Parameters"/>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ambient Temperature"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Barometric Pressure"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rd_temp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:id="@+id/rd_pressure"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ambient Light"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Humidity"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rd_light"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rd_humidity"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </TableRow>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp" />

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Main Activity onCreate()

```
                    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

            ...

            Toolbar vToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);                               
            setSupportActionBar(vToolbar);                                                         
            // Initialise list view adapter
            ListView vListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            vLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
            vListView.setAdapter(vLeDeviceListAdapter);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your parent layout from relative layout to linear layout with vertical orientation and provide fixed height for toolbar

or

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"/>

<TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/table"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_below ="@+id/tool_bar">


    <TextView
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Local Environmental Parameters"/>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ambient Temperature"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Barometric Pressure"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rd_temp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:id="@+id/rd_pressure"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ambient Light"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Humidity"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rd_light"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rd_humidity"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </TableRow>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below ="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp" />

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I had already attempted your first solution with no luck, however your second one did work! I had accidentally set my toolbar background colour to white too so I couldn't actually see it. - Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use coordinator Layout see Some Below Sample

here Frame Layout and View Pager or My content Replace with Yours

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"

app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/hfp_container"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_fab"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```